# Solid vs Gradient Bar-Plot colors

Tags: core-plot

I'm trying to create a simple solid-color bar graph, and I'm working with Core Plot.
All I can find is the tubularBarPlotWithColor method:

```
+(CPTBarPlot *)tubularBarPlotWithColor:(CPTColor *)color horizontalBars:(BOOL)horizontal;
```

Is there an equivalent 'flatBarPlotWithColor' (non-gradient) method?

...I just found an answer via an instantiated method:

```
plot.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]];
```

Still, it would be nice to have a simple class method to handle this.

Ric.

Comment: I believe I have the answer:
    plot.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]];

Answer (score 0):

Just use `+alloc` / `-initWithFrame:` like any other layer and then set the fill to whatever you want. The tubular bar method is just a convenient way to construct the gradient fill.